# How to pass an enum as an argument in C# to a C function

Tags: c#, enums

I want to call a C function from C#. I made the following prototype for C#:

```
XBaseNamespace.cs
-----------------
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace XBaseNamespace.SecondNamespace
{
    class XBaseFunctions
    {
        enum DSM_DIRECTION { FORWARD, BACKWARD };

        [DllImport("W:\\Dropbox\\DSI (His)\\Windows Apps\\Debug\\DsiLibrary_CSharp.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int XBaseDefineFile(int fileNumber, int fileSize, int wordsPerRecord, string fileType, DSM_DIRECTION fileDirection, out int pCurrentRecord);
    }
}

Program.cs
----------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//  Bring in XBASE linkage
using XBaseNamespace.SecondNamespace;

namespace Call_C
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int currentRecord;
            XBaseFunctions.XBaseDefineFile(2500, 32767, 80, "L", XBaseFunctions.DSM_DIRECTION.FORWARD, out currentRecord);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
1>W:\Dropbox\DSI (His)\Windows Apps\Testing\C_sharp\Call_C\XBaseNamespace.cs(25,34,25,49): error CS0051: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'XBaseFunctions.DSM_DIRECTION' is less accessible than method 'XBaseFunctions.XBaseDefineFile(int, int, int, string, XBaseFunctions.DSM_DIRECTION, out int)'
```

So I tried using

```
XBaseNamespace.SecondNamespace.XBaseFunctions.DSM_DIRECTION.FORWARD
```

But get a similar error.

I have checked several references but none of them address this issue.

Can someone help?

Comment: Try making the enum `public`, it is `private` by default, specifying the namespace doesn't help with that. Also note that since you didn't specify an access modifier for your `XBaseFunctions` class, it is `internal` by default.

Answer (score 2):

You've declare the `enum` inside of a `class` without an access modifier. By default, it is `private`.

Your method is `public`, but nothing calling the method would have access to the `enum` so the structure can't work. Hence the error.

Simply adding the `public` modifier to your `enum` should take care of that error. It may also make sense to move the `enum` out of the class but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to:

        public enum DSM_DIRECTION { FORWARD, BACKWARD };

But that gave:

error CS0117: 'DSM_DIRECTION' does not contain a definition for 'FORWARD'